How can I view a file version of Native AOT C# application in linux?
I have a C# console application compiled to Native AOT.
The code below works well when running on Windows, and it displays correct file version:
var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(exePath);
string version = versionInfo.FileVersion;

But in Linux (Ubuntu using Docker) version variable returns null;
Is it possible to view the file version in Linux?
Note, that version check code is running from another application.
I also noticed that FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo in Linux works well for .dll files, but Native AOT application contains only exe.
The native AOT application is compiled for Windows.

I use this, not sure if it's equivalent.
Assembly currentAssem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var ver =  currentAssem.GetName().Version;

@bmiller not sure it will work, because Native AOT does not contain traditional assembly, it is a byte code

You're right, I thought my MVC app was AOT but it's not supported - nor is Blazer server or SignalR.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/native-aot?view=aspnetcore-8.0
